# How to count all subfolders in an directory?

Tags: linux, find, directory, count

How can I count how many folders (including subfolders) I have under an specific folder?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `find` to select the directories and `wc` to count them.

```
find <directory> -mindepth 1 -type d | wc -l
```

Comment: Wow, is there an faster solution? ;-)
-------------------------------------------------
time find product_images/ -mindepth 1 -type d | wc -l
574292

real    67m34.672s
user    0m4.272s
sys     0m35.790s
-------------------------------------------------

Comment: That's a big tree. The only way you can speed it up is to work on an index of that structure. But creating and updating the index will be just as slow. And the most common tool for indexing and searching the local FS, `locatedb`, won't allow you to refine your search in the same way as `find`.

Comment: yes, with 574292 subdirs and who knows what many files, it's the fastest way to cound the dirs

Comment: What if some subfoldernames have \n in their names? Wouldn't those be counted twice or more?

Answer (score 0):

tree -d  | grep directories | awk -F' ' '{print $1}'

Comment: I'd use `tail` since there could be a directory called "directories" and there's no need for the -F with the awk: `tree -d|tail -n1|awk '{print $1}'`